# How to ignore a certificate error with c# 2.0 WebClient - without the certificate

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, webclient

Using Visual Studio 2005 - C# 2.0, `System.Net.WebClient.UploadData(Uri address, byte[] data)`  Windows Server 2003

So here's a stripped down version of the code:

```cs
static string SO_method(String fullRequestString)
{
    string theUriStringToUse = @"https://10.10.10.10:443"; // populated with real endpoint IP:port
    string proxyAddressAndPort = @"http://10.10.10.10:80/"; // populated with a real proxy IP:port
    Byte[] utf8EncodedResponse; // for the return data in utf8
    string responseString; // for the return data in utf16

    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient(); // instantiate a web client
    WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy(proxyAddressAndPort, true);// instantiate & popuylate a web proxy
    myWebClient.Proxy = proxyObject; // add the proxy to the client
    myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // stick some stuff in the header

    UTF8Encoding utf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);// create a utf8 encoding
    Byte[] utf8EncodedRequest = HttpUtility.UrlEncodeToBytes(fullRequestString, utf8Encoding); // convert the request data to a utf8 byte array

    try
    {
        utf8EncodedResponse = myWebClient.UploadData(theUriStringToUse, "POST", utf8EncodedRequest); // pass the utf8-encoded byte array
        responseString = utf8Encoding.GetString(utf8EncodedResponse); // get a useable string out of the response
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // some other error handling
        responseString = "<CommError><![CDATA[" + e.ToString() + "]]></CommError>";// show the basics of the problem
    }
    return responseString;// return whatever ya got
}
```

This is the error I get:

> **The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.**

I don't have much control to see what's happening when the request goes out.  I'm told that it's reaching the correct destination and there's a "certificate error". This is supposedly because there's a literal mismatch between the IP address in my request and the URL it resolves to.   I have more than one IP I'm supposed to round-robin to so specifying the URL won't work.    I'm not attaching a certificate - nor am I supposed to according to the endpoint owners.  Per "them" the certificate error is 'normal and I am supposed to ignore it.

The cert in question is supposedly one of the many verisign certs that is "just there" on our server.  The examples I've seen for ignoring cert errors all seem to imply that the requestor is attaching a specific x509 certificate (which I'm not).

I looked over [.net WebService, bypass ssl validation!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721472/net-webservice-bypass-ssl-validation) which kinda-sorta describes my problem - except it also kinda-sorta doesn't because I don't know which certificate (if any) I should reference.

Is there a way for me to ignore the error without actually knowing/caring what certificate is causing the problem?

- and please - kid gloves, small words, and "for dummies" code as I'm not exactly a heavy hitter.
- This traffic is over a private line - so my understanding is that ignoring the cert error is not as big a deal as if it were open internet traffic.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The SSL certificate is for a machine to establish a trust relationship. If you type in one IP address, and end up talking to another, that sounds the same as a DNS hijack security fault, the kind of thing SSL is intending to help you avoid - and perhaps something you don't want to put up with from "them".

If you may end up talking to more than machine (ideally they would make it appear as one for you), you will need a certificate for each of the possible machines to initiate trust.

To ignore trust (I've only ever had to do this temporarily in development scenarios) the following snippet may work for you, but I strongly recommend you consider the impact of ignoring trust before using it:

```cs
public static void InitiateSSLTrust()
{
    try
    {
        //Change SSL checks so that all checks pass
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
           new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
                delegate
                { return true; }
            );
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ActivityLog.InsertSyncActivity(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, MattH.  I'm executing the code you have in the TRY block jut prior to invoking the System.Net.WebClient.UploadData(Uri address, byte[] data) method.  To say that I'm not sure what it's doing would be an understatement. I don't see the tie-in to my WebClient.   However, it "appears" to be working as we seem to be getting further in our communication per the network team on my side.  I found A very similar suggestion on MSDN but the words just want to bounce off my eyeballs.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: In a nutshell the above code trusts anybody, and bypasses all SSL verification, and is therefore not secure.

Comment: Right - that much I got - but is this tied to my specific instance of a WebClient, my running process, or to ANY cert related "goings on" on the server once this executes?   My guess is it's limited to my process but...

Comment: Oh - yeah - This traffic is over a private line -- just added a bullet indicating as much in the question.  But then I'm thinking - I know there's not a physical private cable from our site to the other party.  All them wires in the middle must be sharing other traffic...

Answer (score 24):

I realize this is an old post, but I just wanted to show that there is a more short-hand way of doing this (with .NET 3.5+ and later).

Maybe it's just my OCD, but I wanted to minimize this code as much as possible.  This seems to be the shortest way to do it, but I've also listed some longer equivalents below:

```
// 79 Characters (72 without spaces)
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;
```

Shortest way in .NET 2.0 (which is what the question was specifically asking about)

```
// 84 Characters
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

It's unfortunate that the lambda way requires you to define the parameters, otherwise it could be even shorter.

And in case you need a much longer way, here are some additional alternatives:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, errors) => true;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors) { return true; };

// 255 characters - lots of code!
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
        delegate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
        {
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: While this may have it's use case if you want to disable certificate validation in your main class, you should keep in mind, that this could lead to a potential memory leak, if used inside a class that is constructed per request. Also `+=` would be used to subscribe to this callback.

Answer (score 12):

This is somewhat the code we're using (not polished yet - I don't think I have the error-handling setup correctly but it should be close) based on thomas's suggestion (this is .NET 4.0 code, though):

```
var sslFailureCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });

try
{

    if (ignoreSslErrors)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += sslFailureCallback;
    }

    response = webClient.UploadData(Options.Address, "POST", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Options.PostData));

}
catch (Exception err)
{
    PageSource = "POST Failed:\r\n\r\n" + err;
    return PageSource;
}
finally
{
    if (ignoreSslErrors)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= sslFailureCallback;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This code is much broader than you might expect.  It is process-wide.  The process might be the exe, IIS on this machine, or even DLLHost.exe.  After calling it, have a finally block that restores things to normal by removing the delegate that always returns true.

Comment: If the process has other threads running that are making calls, the callback will still be used while it's set though.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to disable SSL verification for a specific domain without globally deactivating it because there might be other requests running which should not be affected, so I came up with this solution (please note that uri is a variable inside a class:

```
        private byte[] UploadValues(string method, NameValueCollection data)
        {
            var client = new WebClient();

            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                    ServerCertificateValidation;

                returnrclient.UploadValues(uri, method, parameters);

            }
            finally
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -=
                    ServerCertificateValidation;
            }
        }

        private bool ServerCertificateValidation(object sender,
            X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
            SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            var request = sender as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request != null && request.Address.Host.Equals(
                this.uri.Host, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the VB.net code to make WebClient ignore the SSL cert.

```
Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Function() True)
```